# sudo: script launched from another script won't redirect standard output

Tags: stdout, sudo

I'm using AIX 5.3 with sudo 1.6.9p23. Sudoers file grants user fcomartin permission to run any command as user oas:

```
fcomarti ALL=(oas) ALL
```

User oas has a bash script called menu, from which it launches another scripts depending on the selected option. The problem is that some of the secondary scripts redirects standard output to text file "temp" which is owned by oas user, when this happens the system tells me that user do not have the right permissions to write.

User fcomarti uses ksh, then the used command is as follows:

```
sudo -u oas bash menu
```

(bash because user oas uses bash) Menu starts, menu launches monitorAv script, inside monitorAv is the line echo > temp, it then tells user fcomarti it do not have the right permissions to write.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally solved the problem, the sintaxis of sudo is as follows:

```
sudo -u oas bash -c "cd /Oas/bin; menu"
```

This is because some of the secondary scripts launched by menu, needs an absolute route to work.

Answer (score 0):

The script is running as user `oas`, not as user `fcomarti`, so if it is trying to write to a file in a directory owned by `fcomarti` it is probably not going to have the appropriate permissions.

You could make user `oas` share a group with user `fcomarti` and then grant group write permissions on certain directories, or you can have the script output to a location that is writeable by the `oas` user (e.g., `/tmp`, or some directory you have explicitly created for that purpose, such as the `HOME` directory for user `oas`).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, actually the text file "temp" is in a folder owned by user oas, it's like if the secondary scripts launched by menu won't inherit the user oas, so the instruction echo > temp fails to write.

Comment: Are you sure?  There's no magic in `sudo`; once you've started running things as the `oas` user, all subsequent commands will run as that user (absent another call to `sudo`, `su`, or some other privileged tool).  I would double check your current directory when trying to generate the output file, or output using an explicit path instead of a relative path.